Short mantras for Ganesha and maa Saraswati
I have seen the Medha suktam of maa Saraswati , but I want a shorter mantra which can be chanted to get the blessings of maa sarswati for blessings of intelligence , and success in exams . Can any one tell some authentic scripture prescribed mantras which can give me the blessings of maa Saraswati . Also are there any such mantras for lord Ganesha ? Thank you.

For Ganesha mantras see this link -- https://www.drikpanchang.com/vedic-mantra/gods/lord-ganesha/ganesha-mantras.html .. you will possibly find a similar list for Saraswati in the same website.

Some of them are Beeja mantras which I don’t want to chant and others I don’t think are authentic. @Rickross

@Rickross Could you please check whether the Gayatri mantra of the Ganesha is authentic or not as I have earlier asked , there is only one Gayatri mantra of savitur only.

I have posted an answer ..

As per the Linga Purana the Gayatri mantra for Lord Ganesha is Om tatpurushaaya vidmahey Vakratundaaya Dhimahi, Tanno Dantih prachodayaat.

26    Varied Swarupas of Gayatri The various Swarupas of Gayatri as
created by Maha Deva and the related Mantras are::
Tatpurushaaya vidmahey Vaagshuddhaaya Dhimahi tannah Shivah
Prachodayaat
Ganaambikaayai vidmahey Karma saadhyaih cha dhimahi, Tanno Gauri
Prachodayaat/
Tatpurushaaya vidmahey Maha Devaaya Dhimahi, Tanno Rudrah
prachodayaat/
Tatpurushaaya vidmahey Vakratundaaya Dhimahi, Tanno Dantih prachodayaat/


The same Gayatri mantra is mentioned in the Mahanarayana Upanishad (https://vignanam.org/english/maha-narayana-upanishad.html) too:

gāyatrī mantrāḥ (4.2)
puru̍ṣasya vidma sahasrā̠kṣasya̍ mahādē̠vasya̍ dhīmahi । tannō̍ rudraḥ
prachō̠dayā̎t ॥ tatpuru̍ṣāya vi̠dmahē̍ mahādē̠vāya̍ dhīmahi ।
tannō̍ rudraḥ prachō̠dayā̎t ॥।
tatpuru̍ṣāya vi̠dmahē̍ vakratu̠ṇḍāya̍ dhīmahi । tannō̍ dantiḥ prachō̠dayā̎t ॥ tatpuru̍ṣāya vi̠dmahē̍ chakratu̠ṇḍāya̍ dhīmahi ।
tannō̍ nandiḥ prachō̠dayā̎t ॥


Thank you very much .
